# Necessary to live, painful to bear

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I burn without flame, though you may disagree,
> I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.
>
> I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,
> I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.
>
> I trap people, who are tied to the past.

What am I?

Comment: No Acrostic!? ...or is there? ;)

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails, Oh, there most certainly is. (Evil Laughter)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> A heart

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> Heart burn

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> Human heart can feel many emotions, some of which are empathy and sympathy.

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> today an enlarged heart or a blocked heart are more common, but usually it will last throughout your entire lifetime without much problem.

I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> your heart can technically stop at any time, and affects you greatly.

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> people can be stuck in regret with a heavy heart. they are trapped in their memories and their feelings, all of which affect the heart's function- after all, people (and animals) can die of depression.

The acrostic:

> burst (minus the "I" to find it.) Your heart can burst with joy, with regret, etc.

Comment: Hurray! You got it! Good job!

Comment: Darn, this was my second guess. Well done!

Comment: Nice one! Haha @Joe-You-Know had us all on a fun little goose chase but glad the goose is finally caught! :D

Comment: @Joe-You-Know This answerer's username explains the acrostic.

Answer (score 7):

I feel like this may be one more wrong answer amongst many, but there's one thing that comes to mind that the other answers miss, namely:

> Love

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> When love strikes, your heart burns, though those who have not experienced it might not sympathise.

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> When love cannot be fulfilled, your heart stings with pain.

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> When love fails, the resulting heartbreak can be difficult to overcome.

I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> You cannot suppress love, and it strikes whether you are prepared for it or not.

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> Some people become trapped, obsessing over past loves.

As for the second letter of each line:

> BURST: Your heart bursts with love!

Comment: This was a heck of an answer as well! Really close! :)

Comment: If the actual answer wasn't given, I would have accepted this one instead...

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Feeling/grudges

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> All sorts of feelings cause different results, but some people would say they don't have feelings.

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> If you have your feelings hurt you feel sad.

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> It could take one words to hurt someones feelings.

I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> You have feelings all the time.

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> Grudges

Hidden hint

> "I" have feelings

Comment: This answer is too general (well the first answer is). It's a little more specific than this.

Comment: Could it be (Natre, wrnybhfl, rpg?) @Joe-You-Know

Comment: it's not necessarily so negative.

Comment: Dang, I thought it was definitely a (tehqtr)

Answer (score 3):

Since the answer is not

> Memories

Could this be

> A boil? (Alternate answer: Your Appendix/Appendicitis)

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> Boils can feel like a burning sensation on your skin, and they can be really painful  (Appendicitis can feel like your stomach area is burning)

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> Really, **really** painful (Appendicitis is really painful as well)

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> You can puncture a boil fairly easily, although if you don't touch them, some may get too big to be drained and last a very long time (The appendix can rupture fairly easily, causing a form of appendicitis; although for some people the appendix can remain intact for their entire lives)

I *surcease* uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> Boils tend not to just "go away", and from what I've heard, although removing one is easy, it's also painful. If you don't remove it, they can continue being painful for a long time (Also, appendicitis needs surgery to resolve -- it doesn't stop very easily either. It can also affect people whenever, it doesn't have to happen to people of a certain age)

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> Boils that happened a long time ago trap people with the pain (Appendicitis is a "trap", because the appendix is a vestigial organ which ties modern humans to earlier humans/primates who needed it to digest raw meat)

Also,

> The second letter of each line spells "BURST".....this could refer to bursting a boil or the appendix bursting.

Comment: This isn't a bad guess, but it's not what I'm looking for. You're on the right path though.

Comment: Hmm, my acrostic seems to have the opposite effect that I wanted it to. Your first answer was much closer.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know But what if I feel emotions in my appendix??? ;P

Comment: Just like how I feel with my Squeedily spooch

Comment: Um excuse me, I thought we were keeping this comment thread PG (is that what the kids are calling that these days?)

Comment: It's an invader zim reference, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37ERbN2eb0o

Answer (score 3):

Are you perhaps:

> Regret?

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> The pain of regret is often a "burning" feeling, but there is no literal flame

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> We all have regrets, and it is one of the most painful things that you can have.

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> Your regrets can surface easily, and often last forever

I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> Regrets are hard to get rid of, and they will affect you no matter the circumstance

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> Your regrets are in your past, and you will be burdened by regrets if you live in the past and don't move on

No idea about the acrostic, but this is the best I've got.

Comment: This is close. You could say the answer can cause regret.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Mistakes/humiliation?

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> When you make a mistake or are humiliated, sometimes it feels that your cheeks are burning (but no flame)

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> It feels bad to make mistakes and the sting of humiliation is painful

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> Usually mistakes or humiliating moments are over quickly, but people remembering them (or really big mistakes) can last forever

I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> It's hard for people to live down mistakes or humiliating moments, and sometimes can affect people at random times

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> Mistakes and humiliating moments can trap people who focus on past events and their previous shortcomings

The hint,

> the acrostic, "BURST" could be because people in these situations feel like they want to burst when these things happen

Comment: Think more positively, but not a bad guess.

Comment: Hmm...interesting that the answer is positive when so much of the question has negative connotations!!

Comment: Positive is probably the wrong word. Let's say it's neutral. It can be positive and negative.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Revenge

I burn without flame, though you may disagree,

> Revenge consumes people like a flame,though people who seek revenge does not admit it

I understand your pain, which stings worse than a bee.

> Those who seek revenge are usually in emotional pain because of a past event

I rupture easily, even though I can last forever,

> Some people can't let go of their desire for revenge

I surcease uneasily, I will affect you whenever.

> The thoughts of revenge is hard to leave behind

I trap people, who are tied to the past.

> Again, people that can't leave the past behind are consumed by revenge

Comment: This is really close, but not quite the answer I'm looking for. P.S. The acrostic in this riddle may help.

Comment: I prefer new answers to edits too.